# How to get guest's IP address from Host server in KVM virtualization?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, kvm, hypervisor, virsh

I used kvm as a hypervisor and I have some virtual machines on it. 
I can to ssh to the host (hypervisor server) and I want to get all virtual machines' IP addresses.

Is there any way to get the virtual machines' IP addresses by *virt* tool or other commands like this?

Comment: You have the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19057915/libvirt-fetch-ipv4-address-from-guest?

Comment: That answer isn't work for me. It used arp -e , but this solution is not comprehensive!

Comment: What language are you working in? Libvirt has language bindings for dozens of languages.

Answer (score 1):

Try this commands from the console of the host machine:

```
# virsh list --all
Get the VM names from this list
```

Now for each VM name do the following:

```
# virsh domiflist *VMname*
Get the MAC of the VM machine

# arp -e 
Find the IP address
```

Ping the hostname from the KVM host and you can get the IPS address.